# Why does my external hard drive read and write speed drop to 0

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, performance, disk, io

I recently got a new external hard drive and have noticed that the write speeds are very slow. When I used "Benchmark Partition" from the Disks utility, I got a very strange result:

[image: weird benchmark]

Why are the hard drive read and write speeds occasionally hitting 0? Is this just a defective drive?

Answer (score 0):

You may read this [forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/super-slow-hdd-transfer-speeds-4175679576/). Generally, external HDD drives due to high temperatures may slow down. This means their manufactures must install a cooling systm maybe?